# Import and export database in 11g

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I want to create new database in oracle. But In that database i want to export and import database table from other database.

For example: 
I have database name like: ABC

In this database (ABC) I have some tables like table1, table2.

I want to copy these table as it in to other database name XYZ.

Can I do that? If yes then how?

I am Using Oracle 11g

Answer (score 2):

Use datapump to move data from one database to another. See : 
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php